# Cartoon with sentient trees and an environmental message

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I think watched this cartoon in the 1950s or 1960s in Chicago. Beautifully rendered art. I don't recall if there was spoken dialogue. It was about a tree couple - a big male tree (oak?) and a smaller female tree (birch? linden?) - who were tormented by a thoughtless boy. They pulled up their roots and walked away, changing the local weather for the worse. No shade, no place for the birds to roost. At some point, there is a big storm and a flooded river, and either they saved the boy or the female tree. And the boy repented, and the trees returned. The last scene shows the happy trees and wildlife.

I thought it might have been made in Europe - definitely not in the style of Disney or Warner Bros. that I was familiar with at the time. However, digging into animation databases I can see that some of the Silly Symphony cartoons from Disney and the detail you can see in some of the other American studios is similar.

It was in rotation on weekends with a bunch of other cartoons that I have never seen since. Been looking for it for years. A tearjerker for sure.

Because of another recent success I started looking at lists of cartoons using keywords of *tree* and *boy.* No luck as yet. And it is not *Flowers and Trees,* the famous Disney cartoon.

Comment: There were a lot of cartoons with inanimate objects (including trees) suddenly appearing animate, with eyes and mouths. I guess all cartoons are fantasy -- Mickey Mouse, Bugs Bunny, etc. because we have talking animals -- but are cartoons part of Fantasy as defined here or is there some other place better to ask specifically about cartoons?

Comment: These were sentient living trees from the beginning, not "suddenly" as you describe. Walked around like Ents as I recall. Where else might I post this request?

Comment: I don't know, I am just saying that cartoons, even Simpsons, have often a strong element of fantasy. Cartoons/comics could probably be a separate stackexchange. I have no objection to anyone asking any sort of question here, just pointing out this aspect of cartoons.

Comment: Cartoon is a tag on this site, and I have seen lots of questions having to do with fantasy and fairy tale cartoons. A cartoon about sentient trees that feel and express emotions, use their branches as arms and hands, and their roots as legs and feet, as a central theme, is likely acceptable. But perhaps other people object as well?

Comment: not objecting, as i indicated

Comment: Well, feedback is always welcome - thank you.

Comment: From the title I was thinking of he animated version of the Dr Suess *The Lorax*. But there are too many mismatches for that to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, but no, it's definitely not a Suess. The images look hand-drawn, as I recall, like an old-fashioned children's book.

Comment: I agree with the comments about is this fantasy, maybe we should 'branch out' into a separate Stack Exchange. (I don't really think that btw - I just wanted to get in the pun about branch in a discussion about trees)

Comment: I live with a punster, so I appreciate your efforts (grin).

Comment: So basically you watched it on TV and not on a VHS? Was it black and white or with colours? Any channel comes to mind? Sometimes, remembering the channel narrows down to a list of stuffs that were aired on a list on Wikipedia for example.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, this was on television over 60 years ago. No VHS, no cable, probably WGN, because they were were my favorite channel for cartoons when I was a kid. It was in rotation with other cartoons of its ilk. I thought it might be one of the  Silly Symphony cartoons, but I reviewed the titles and plots for ALL 75. Nope. Thanks for asking. Wish I could give you more. I think it was in color, but I don't trust my memory.